# hide columns on inserting in data grid devextreme

Tags: jquery, html, devextreme, dx-data-grid

Is there any way to hide a column on inserting  data grid?
I have a grid that one cells have multi command buttons. But when I want to insert or update for those buttons it renders an empty textbox. How can I remove the textbox in inserting and updating?

I have tried this but I don't know how can I hide it:

```
columns:[...
    {
                allowHiding:true,
                cellTemplate: function (container, options) {

                    $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"/>').addClass('dx-button btnLinkGrid')
                    .text('Commission')
                    .on('dxclick', function (info) {
                        var url = '/finantialinfo/commision';
                        window.location.href = url;
                    })
                    .appendTo(container);

                    $('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"/>').addClass('dx-button btnLinkGrid')
                    .text('Restitution')
                    .on('dxclick', function (info) {
                        var url = '/finantialinfo/restitution';
                        window.location.href = url;
                    })
                    .appendTo(container);
                }
            }...
]
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear. Could you modify this [sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqLKGm) and describe step-by-step what would you like to do?

Comment: i have a data grid in devextreme . in column (like the code above) i have a cloumn that have multiple columns that every one on them are links to another page. but in inserting or in editing i have a textbox for those btns. how can i remove this text box that rendered in edit and insert mode for those btns? @Sergey

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lemanslmi/eyLwyn2x/2/ @Sergey

Comment: Got it. You are using `editing.mode = "form"`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you need to customize an editing form. Well, you can use the [column.formItem](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/columns/#formItem) option like below:

```
columns: [{
    /*...*/
    formItem: { visible: false }
}]
```

I've updated your [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/sergfry/eyLwyn2x/3/) as well.