# DevExtreme Hide Column EditMode Angular2

Tags: angular, grid, devextreme, dx-data-grid

how can I hide a DataGrid Column in EditMode using DevExtreme and Angular2?

```
<h3>Test</h3>
<dx-data-grid id="gridContainer" 
[dataSource]="xxx" 
[allowColumnReordering]="true" 
[allowColumnResizing]="true" 
[rowAlternationEnabled]="true">
<dxo-column-chooser [enabled]="true"></dxo-column-chooser>
    <dxi-column dataField="Id" 
    [visible]="false" 
    [width]="50"
    [allowEditing]="false" ></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Name"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Type"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Data"></dxi-column>
    <dxo-editing mode="form"
                 [allowUpdating]="true"
                 [allowDeleting]="true"
                 [allowAdding]="true">
    </dxo-editing>
</dx-data-grid>
```

The Column is not shown on the Grid, but on the Editform..

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The similar question is here - [hide columns on inserting in data grid devextreme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778989/hide-columns-on-inserting-in-data-grid-devextreme)

But in Angular2 approach code should be like below:

```
<dxi-column dataField="Id" 
    [visible]="false" 
    [width]="50"
    [formItem]="{visible: false}"
    [allowEditing]="false" ></dxi-column>
```

This line `[formItem]="{visible: false}"` is useful for you.